# Why does it suffice to prove Hölder's inequality for $||f||_p = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The theorem that I wish to prove based on Durrett's book is the following:

> Theorem 1.2.5 **Hölder's inequality**. If $ p, q \in (1, \infty) $ with $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 $ then
>   $$ \int | f g | d \mu \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q $$

Durrett argues the following way:

> If $||f||_p = 0 $ or $||g||_p = 0 $ then $|fg|$ = 0 a.e., (yes), so it suffices prove the result when $||f||_p$ and $||g||_q > 0$ (I agree), **or by dividing both sides by** $||f||_p ||g||_q$ **when** $||f||_p = ||g||_q = 1$

I'm confused about the last part, because I'm not sure what equation Durrett refers to (the proposition or the inequality?) and in both cases, why that might be true?

In fact, argue that the trivial case is proved, so then we can assume
$ ||f||_p > 0 $, and $ ||g||_p > 0 $, then the suggested division leads to
$ 1 > ||g||_p $ and $ 1 > ||f||_p $, which does not even allow equality.

The remaining part of the proof I understand, but I'm confused why this is true.

Comment: Yes, it is written in the post, but I will state it in bold for ease of understanding.

Comment: See [this Terry Tao blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/amplification-arbitrage-and-the-tensor-power-trick/) (only the first section). This is an instance of a "gauge fixing"; the Hölder inequality has an homogeneity symmetry, which you can "spend" by "fixing a gauge", in physicist's jargon. (Ignore this comment if you find it confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the result is true when $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_p=1$. Then for the general case, consider the functions $\dfrac{f}{\|f\|_p}$ and $\dfrac{g}{\|g\|_p}$. Note that $\left\|\dfrac{f}{\|f\|_p}\right\|_p=1.$

---

$$\|af\|_p=\left(\int{\lvert af(x) \rvert^p}\right)^{1/p}=\left(\int|a|^p\cdot{\lvert f(x) \rvert^p}\right)^{1/p}=|a|\left(\int{\lvert f(x) \rvert^p}\right)^{1/p}=|a|\|f\|_p$$ for any $a\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why the last equality is the case? I see it in terms of p=1 quite easily, so I get the intuition, but applying the definition of the norm directly I can't see it still.

Comment: Please see my edit. Note that $\|f\|_p$ is always a non-negative real.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppose with out loss of generality that $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_q=1$, because Holder inequality hold if and only if $$\int |rh|\leq 1,$$
where $r=\frac{f}{\|f\|_p}$ and $h=\frac{g}{\|g\|_q}.$